# How to set null data in DataTable to empty string

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, dataset, datarow

I populated `datatable` object with data from database, and I need to check if some of them are `NULL` and set it to **empty string**. 
The problem is that some data are `NULL` in database but they are **"0"** in DataTable.
I have tried to set to `""`, `String.EmptyString` etc. nothing works.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        object value = row[c];

        if (value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            try
            {
                row[c] = "";
```

Comment: "The problem is that some data are NULL in database but they are "0" in DataTable." I don't believe you. :) Can you write a sample program to demonstrate this? I've NEVER seen this behavior before.

Comment: You need to first understand that the Database Schema if it allows nulls then setting to string.empty will work .if not then you need to set the null values to DBNUll and "" is not the same as setting to null

Comment: Believe me :) In int column is null and date column is null. I DataTable in `Row.ItemArray[0]=0`, `Row.ItemArray[0]={1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM}`.

Answer (score 2):

try changing to;

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        if (row.IsNull(c))
        {
            try
            {
                row[c] = string.Empty;
```

The `row.IsNull(c)` check is more reliable than directly comparing to `DBNull.Value` as it can evaluate more than one thing as equivilent to `NULL` in the DB.